# Read Url-part with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url

How can I read the last folder from the URL with JavaScript ?

I have a URL like this:

```
http://www.example.org/folder1/folder2/folder3
```

How can I read the last folder-name (folder3 in this example) with JavaScript, and put it in a variable ?

Answer (score 5):

The fastest option is probably `split`:

```
var folder = url.split('/').pop();
```

Depending on how well you know the input, you might need to do some extra work, e.g. stripping off a trailing `/`.